# 'GithubOrganizationManager' object has no attribute 'organization_name'

Tags: python-3.x, github

AttributeError: 'GithubManager' object has no attribute 'organization_name'

I think this some issue with initialization of the instances.

Hello everyone,
I am using this class

class GithubManager:
**slots** = []
MIN_PREFIX_LENGTH = 3

```
def __init__(self, organization_name):
    self.organization_name = organization_name
    self._config = self.read_config()

 def read_config(self):
    config_file_name = "example-conf.yml"
    try:
        with open(config_file_name) as config_file:
            config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
            return config
    except IOError:
            raise SystemExit
```

calling this class from main
manager = GithubManager(organization_name)

But,whatever i try, i am getting the same error.